# unable to display big address into the edittext

Tags: java, android, xml

[from location wont work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMYUY.jpg)when i clicked button then it shows multiple addresses.After selecting big address then half of the text is not visible in the edittext.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/txtFromCity"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.60"
android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
android:text=""
android:maxLength="100"
android:hint="Required"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Small"
style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Comment: i have used inputtype=textMultiLine but it wont work

Comment: you gave maxLength="100"  cause of this it is half. remove this or increase the length

Comment: @AbhinavGupta increase length but still wont work

Comment: remove the length and test it if it will not work then use maxLines ="10"

Comment: Can you post screenshot?

Comment: @Azhar92 posted screenshot of from location

Comment: remove the weight

Answer (score 0):

try this code hope so work.

```
<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
android:lines="8" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
android:minLines="6" <!-- Minimum lines -->
android:gravity="top|left" <!-- Cursor Position -->
android:maxLines="10" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Height determined by content -->
android:layout_width="match_parent" <!-- Fill entire width -->
android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- Vertical Scroll Bar -->
/>
```